# Is there a way to drop rows from a dataframe by comparing a column value to values in list?

Tags: python, pandas, rows, drop

I have a dataframe with three columns. I am trying to clean the data by dropping all the rows that do not have country names in the third column. Or basically I am trying to drop all the values in that third column that are not countries.

For that, I added a list of the country names to my notebook and now I would like to know if it is possible to drop all the values in that column that are not found in the list of countries?

The problem might be, that the values in the column are one big string of text from a product text of an HTML file. I already split the strings and dropped a couple of rows based on ";" and length, but now I am not sure how to continue.

I tried:

```
ProductDataFrame =
ProductDataFrame[~ProductDataFrame['Produkttext'].isin(CountriesList)]
```

which doesn't return an error but does not change anything in my dataframe...

This is what it looks like:

```
                                                                  Produkttext  
1                                                             Roter Kopfsalat.   
2                                                                       Italien  
3                                 Äthiopien,Marokko, Senegal, Ruanda oder Kenia  
4                                                                       Spanien  
5                                                                   Deutschland  
6                                           Deutschland, Niederlande oder Polen  
7                                                      Deutschland oder Italien  
8                                          Deutschland, Frankreich oder Italien  
9                                                                   Deutschland  
10                                                  Deutschland oder Österreich
```

Comment: What is `CountriesList`? Will you please show a sample of what it is?

Comment: ['Afghanistan', 'Ägypten', 'Ålandinseln', 'Albanien', 'Algerien', 'Amerikanisch-Samoa', 'Amerikanische Jungferninseln', 'Amerikanische Überseeinseln', 'Andorra', 'Angola', 'Anguilla', 'Antarktis', 'Antigua und Barbuda', 'Äquatorialguinea', 'Argentinien', 'Armenien', 'Aruba', 'Aserbaidschan', 'Äthiopien', 'Australien', 'Bahamas', 'Bahrain', 'Bangladesch', 'Barbados', 'Belarus', 'Belgien', 'Belize', 'Benin', 'Bermuda', 'Bhutan', 'Bolivien', 'Bonaire, Sint Eustatius und Saba', 'Bosnien und Herzegowina', 'Botsuana', 'Bouvetinsel', --> --- a list with all countries as strings :)

Comment: So basically you want to remove rows that have none of the items in `CountriesList` in?

Comment: Yes as a first step that would be great at least, but I also want to drop the 'oder's from the column 'Produkttext' and thought maybe that would work also. So basically also only keep values in the column, that are in ```CountriesList```

Comment: What if a row has some of the items in `CountriesList`, but some of its items (excluding "oder") are not in `CountriesList`. Should the whole row be removed? Or should just the items that aren't in `CountriesList` be removed?

Comment: Only the items that are not in ```CountriesList``` should be removed. In the end I just need the corresponding Countries from the products in Column 2. Preferably a a list, I think. I want to have a list of Products and possible countries they came from. Then I want to do this with more datasets and in the end have a list which shows me the product and all possibles countries that it can originate from.

Comment: And I just realised that ```ProductDataFrame = ProductDataFrame[ProductDataFrame['Produkttext'].isin(CountriesList)]``` works but only when there is only one country name in the row in column 3.

Answer (score 0):

After you split by `,`, you can use [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to flatten out all the sublists, then use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html). When you want to group them back together into lists, use [`.groupby(level=0)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) (which groups by the 0th level of the index) and [`.agg(list)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
e = df['Produkttext'].str.split(r'[\s,]+').explode()

# Remove "oder"
e = e[e.ne('oder')]

# Keep only the items that are in CountriesList
e = e[e.isin(CountriesList)]

# Convert the remaining items back to lists
e.groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```